# Central Limit Theorem and Lightbulbs

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, exponential-distribution

"*Suppose I have lightbulbs that have a lifetime which is exponentially distributed with an average lifespan of 5 years. Each time a bulb dies, it is replaced with an another of the same type.*

*What is the probability that in 10 years, at least three bulbs break?*"

So far I have that $\mu=5$, E$[X]=\frac{1}{5}=0.2$, Var$[X]=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}=\frac{1}{25}=0.04$.

My next step was going to be approaching the problem by plugging in these values into the formula for the central limit theorem, namely:

$\chi=\frac{N-0.2}{0.04}$

But this just returns $245$ when I plug in $N=10$ years which doesn't seem to be right. If anyone could explain where my understanding of the topic is failing and where I'm going wrong that would be great.

Comment: Let $X$ denotes the number of lightbulbs that break during this 10 year period. You need to find $P(X\geq 3)$. Do you know the distribution of $X$?

Comment: @MatthewPilling Is it $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$?

Comment: That's the pdf of a (continuous) exponential random variable. $X$ here is discrete, and I'm asking if you can find the *pmf* of $X$

Comment: @MatthewPilling Since it's exponentially distributed, I assume it's not as simple as $\frac{1}{2}$ for it lasting longer than or less than 5 years? I'm looking over my notes and it's giving me an example with die where $X$ is the number that appears and so $f_{X}(x)=P(X=x)=\frac{1}{6}$, I just can't see how to apply that here.

Comment: Have you learned about the Poisson distribution? The problem is trying to have you recognize that you are looking at a Poisson Process.

Comment: Yes. If $X$ represents the number of "arrivals" of new lightbulbs (which is exactly the number of lightbulbs that break) in this ten year period, then you should be able to deduce that $X\sim \text{Poisson}\Big(10\cdot \frac{1}{5}\Big)$

Comment: @MatthewPilling So with parameter 2, the equation I'm dealing with should be $\frac{(0.2\cdot 10)^{10}\cdot e^{-2}}{10!}$?

Comment: That's $P(X=10)$. You need to find $P(X\geq 3)$

Comment: @MatthewPilling So just to make sure I'm understanding correctly, $P(X=10)$ is saying the probability that exactly 10 lightbulbs break in 10 years?

Comment: If $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(2),$ then $P(X \ge 3) = 1 - P(X\le 2) = 0.3233236.$ The CLT has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Multiple Exponential Waiting Time as Poisson or Gamma**

**Poisson** (as in Comments by @MatthewPilling and me): The ten-year mean is $\lambda_{10} = 10(1/5) = 2.$
Let $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda_{10}=2),$ then you
seek $P(X \ge 3) = 1 - P(X \le 2) = 0.3233.$ In R, where
`ppois` is a Poisson CDF:

```
1 - ppois(2, 2)
[1] 0.3233236
```

**Gamma** (equivalently): The waiting time for three successive
exponential failures (mean=5, rate=1/5) is
$W\sim\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=3,\mathrm{rate}=1/5).$
You seek $P(W \le 10) = 0.3233.$
In R, where `pgamma` is a gamma PDF:

```
pgamma(10, 3, 1/5)
[1] 0.3233236
```

*Simulation:*

```
set.seed(1112)
w = replicate(10^6, sum(rexp(3,.2)))
mean(w <= 10)
[1] 0.323841

hist(w, prob=T, br=60, col="skyblue2", 
     main="Wait for 3")
 curve(dgamma(x, 3, .2), add=T, lwd=2, col="orange")
 abline(v=10, lty="dotted", lwd=3, col="darkgreen")
```

[image]